# Backup of a NAS

Tags: backup

I have a NAS that is used to store data from our LAN. For many years I've relied on `tar` or `cpio` to back up selected directories to tape. When I backup complete partitions or disks on the various computers I generally use `dump` as per the recommendation of W. Curtis Preston in *UNIX Backup & Recovery.*

I've recently decided to make one archival backup of the NAS, but it appears that `dump` does not work in my situation, possibly because of the format of the NAS. It is attached to our Linux or FreeBSD machines as a CIFS device at `/media/nas`, and the Windows ones as 'network storage' which I assume is SMB. It is a 2 Terabyte Buffalo Link Station. I would prefer to be able to use `dump` as per Preston's comparison of backup reliability, but will use `cpio` if no one can suggest a viable alternative.

Comment: I looked at DAR and find it a capable solution, but decided to revert to an older backup solution I've used in the past, Bacula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DAR](http://dar.linux.free.fr/). Among other things, it features an incremental mode that runs efficiently. Since your NAS is 2 TB big, being able to do incremental backups is one important feature to consider.

For more details on the relevant DAR calls, see also, e.g. my [DAR script collection](https://bitbucket.org/gsauthof/backup-scripts).

Answer (score 1):

Dump requires direct access to the underlying block device. So you can't use it on a network filesystem, unless you run it on the server (in this case, you'd need to run `dump` on the NAS, not on a client of the NAS). Or remove the drives from the NAS and attach them to a PC, presuming you can assemble any RAID arrays that the NAS created.

As a side note, you might want to get more recent backup advice than a book from 1999.